# How to know the name of a frame to be used in Selenium + Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I have a very simple Python script (which I don't know how to start), regarding selenium, so I want to know how would you know the `'name'/'ID'` of the frame, the one that you can use to identify that specific frame. I would like to ask where can I get that

I don't know if you understand that but, I want to know if how would I recognize that specific frame? 
And also how could I click on that?

Comment: Hey Dave show some HTMl code and work you did so it is easy for us to give answer

Comment: well, I just found some website to play with(the ads)[here](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/IFrame-Inline-Frame)
and the code below is my latest code

Answer (score 1):

well I got this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/IFrame-Inline-Frame')

driver.switch_to_frame("google_ads_iframe_/3618/swht/DEFINITION_0")
# OR we can use XPATH as follows:
#
# element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('PASTE_COPIED_XPATH')
# driver.switch_to.frame(element)  # for switching to the intended frame

element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*
[@id="DfaVisibilityIdentifier_1417699170"]/a/img')
element_to_click.click()

# do whatever you want to do here

driver.switch_to_default_content()  # for switching back to main frame

driver.close()
```

for now it has errors and a long one:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="DfaVisibilityIdentifier_1417699170"]/a/img"}\n  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read the [Selenium documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) first. There are some really nice and simple examples there.

In your case, you can simply right click in anywhere in the frame, and click on 'Inspect' (I'm assuming that you're using Chrome browser). Then in the elements tab, you can find the name / id of that frame. You can find XPath of that frame by right clicking that line, and clicking on 'Copy' > 'Copy XPath'. This applies to clickable element as well. Copy the XPath in the same way, and use click method to click that element.

For switching to a frame, we can also simply use the name of the frame, as follows. We can get the frame name, by right clicking on the element, and observing the HTML code in the developer tools panel's elements tab.

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```

The following code shows how to switch to a frame, and click on an element inside that frame:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('http://www.example.com')

driver.switch_to_frame("REPLACE_ME_WITH_FRAME_NAME_FROM_HTML")
# OR we can use XPATH as follows:
#
# element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('REPLACE_ME_WITH_FRAME_XPATH')
# driver.switch_to.frame(element)  # for switching to the intended frame

element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_xpath('REPLACE_ME_WITH_CLICKABLE_ELEMENT_XPATH')
element_to_click.click()

# do whatever you want to do here

driver.switch_to_default_content()  # for switching back to main frame

driver.close()
```

Although the above example shows XPath, you can use CSS selector as well. But using XPath is recommended.

Comment: thanks, that was fast and reliable but I don't know if this happens to your browser too but I just tried it on an ad(google ad) and can't seem to find it do you think it's normal?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not thinking about tricking Google advertisements. It is not ethical, and Google is smart enough to recognise such activities, and block the payments. 

You should be able to find an element with XPath, unless the site uses some dynamic content eg. flash.

Comment: uh no, just found out that selenium is cool... wanna trick some other guys...but messing with google...what a nice way to die(a little bit exagerrated) and I tried to play with some ads in 'inspect' and I don't know but maybe what I'm looking for is the one that when I put my cursor the ads is highlighted, but wanna ask are those Xpath?

Comment: Hahaha. Good luck with that :)  
Let me know if you have any issues in understanding the above code.

Comment: Do you think the one that I'm looking for is the one that the ads are highlighted when I put my cursor on a code? are those Xpath?

Comment: Nope, that's just the code. Right click on it, and click on copy > copy XPath.  Then the XPath will be copied to your clipboard.

Comment: well, I tried is this it? (//*[@id="mu-1"])
I mean something like this?

Comment: yes, that's it, but you seem to have forgotten to put quotes around it.
It should be `'//*[@id="mu-1"]'` instead of  `//*[@id="mu-1"]`

Comment: thanks man, >just click on the frame> select inspect> loacate the code > right click on it > select "copy as Xpath"....
and about your code above what do you mean "CLICKABLE_ELEMENT_XPATH"?

Comment: thanks that was really useful:
so about the "CLICKABLE_ELEMENT_XPATH" that means the xpath right?
sorry for the trouble

Comment: Correct. Replace that line with xpath of a button you'd like to click. Or anything that you'd like to click./

Comment: I have updated the code to make it more clear to understand.